# Configuring Django with Nginx, uWSGI and Postgres on Docker

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to setup a Django app on Docker with Nginx, uWSGI and Postgres. I found this great guide on setting up Compose for Django and Postgres: https://docs.docker.com/v1.5/compose/django/

However, now I need to add Nginx and uWSGI. I've tried using files of this repo (https://github.com/baxeico/django-uwsgi-nginx) with the Compose setup of the Docker docs but without succes, sadly.

This is what happens when I enter `docker-compose run web`:

```
Step 17 : RUN pip install -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt
 ---> Running in e1ec89e80d9c
Collecting Django==1.9.1 (from -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt (line 1))
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-7.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Downloading Django-1.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6MB)
Collecting psycopg2 (from -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.1.tar.gz (371kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    Please add the directory containing pg_config to the PATH
    or specify the full executable path with the option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XRgbSA/psycopg2
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This is my Dockerfile:

```
from ubuntu:precise

run echo "deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-updates.list

# update packages
run apt-get update

# install required packages
run apt-get install -y python python-dev python-setuptools python-software-properties
run apt-get install -y sqlite3
run apt-get install -y supervisor

# add nginx stable ppa
run add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
# update packages after adding nginx repository
run apt-get update
# install latest stable nginx
run apt-get install -y nginx

# install pip
run easy_install pip

# install uwsgi now because it takes a little while
run pip install uwsgi

# install our code
add . /home/docker/code/

# setup all the configfiles
run echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
run rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
run ln -s /home/docker/code/nginx-app.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
run ln -s /home/docker/code/supervisor-app.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/

# run pip install
run pip install -r /home/docker/code/app/requirements.txt

run cd /home/docker/code/app && ./manage.py syncdb --noinput

expose 80
cmd ["supervisord", "-n"]
```

And the docker-compose.yml:

```
db:
  image: postgres
web:
  build: .
  command: python vms/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"
  links:
    - db
```

There are also files named nginx-app.conf, supervisor-app.conf, uwsgi_params and uwsgi.ini. These are all from the aforementioned repo. Requirements.txt contains Django 1.9.1, psycopg2 and requests.

If there is a better alternative to this Frankenstein project, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Ubuntu, make sure that `python-dev` and `libpq-dev` have been installed using `apt-get`, before trying to install `psycopg2` using pip.

See the [installation docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source) for more info.

Comment: I forgot the libpq-dev, adding it to my dockerfile did the trick. Thank you so much!